# Setting "type" property of HTML Style element reset css rules

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following code:

```
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const style = document.createElement('style');
const rules = {
  '.test': 'width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;',
};
let sheet;

head.appendChild(style);

sheet = style.sheet;

for (const rule in rules) {
  sheet.insertRule(`${rule} {${rules[rule]}}`, 0);
}
```

And it works fine. However, when I set "type" property of HTMLStyleElement after its sheet has been extracted to variable, sheet css rules becomes empty and styles won't be applied to page:

```
head.appendChild(style);

sheet = style.sheet;
style.type = 'text/css'; // it won't work now!
```

Why is it happening? Shouldn't sheet reference be assigned to variable?

JsBin link: https://jsbin.com/gehahiceza/edit?html,js,console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, so here it is, for reference, 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/style

`type` on the style element is an attribute not a property.  the stuff that goes inside of any html element like `<img src="">` src is an attribute, not a property of the img element.

so when you try to assign a value to property of the style variable which is a style element, js will just create a property (type) on the style variable then assign the value you give it.

---

i'm sorry i hadnt answer your question earlier. upon further investigation, i'm finding that .type is already a property on the style element and it should not be used according to [whatgw.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/obsolete.html#attr-style-type) and "In particular, a type value with parameters, such as "text/css; charset=utf-8", will cause this algorithm to return early."[https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-style-element].

i actually observed this behavior from my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rsombhud/10/) where i took your code and added a console.log statement before `sheet.insertRule()` call and after to see what had happened to style.sheet.

just so we're clear, during .insertRule(), the engine is returning a new style element into the child of the head element. in that case, it is being returned prematurely without the added styles in the for in loop.

interestingly, if you do `style.type2 = 'css/text'` or whatever text you want. the return of the style.sheet (CSSStyleSheet) would have the added styles in `rules: ruleList[]`.

i hope this at least provides some additional insights to the reason why the styles arent showing up when doing `style.type = 'css/text'`

Comment: I'm aware of difference between property of JavaScript object and attribute of html element, but what you posted don't answers my problem

Comment: @Furman, i added research and explanation to my reason. hope it helps answer your question this time around.

Answer (score 0):

set type property before adding style element to document.

```js
const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.setAttribute('type', 'text/css'); //!!!!!!!!!!!
const rules = {
  '.test': 'width: 150px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red;',
};
let sheet;

head.appendChild(style);

sheet = style.sheet;


for (const rule in rules) {
  sheet.insertRule(`${rule} {${rules[rule]}}`, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="test">
  </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: I know how to make this code works :) I don't know why it doesn't work in way I asked. It would setting type property of HTMLStyleElement object won't have any impact on reference to its style property - but obviously it does. I don't know why and I want to understand. Thank your for taking your time and posting solution to problem, but it isn't answer to my question. I want to understand why something isn't working, not how to make it work (because I already figured it out)

Comment: maybe this code style.type = 'text/css'; does not trigger DOM or CSSOM to re-rendering.